# Pass a Regular Expression via URL

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have resource endpoint like this: '.../rest/regex/{regex:.+}/matches{value:.+}';
How can i safely pass the regex in the url? How do I encode it?

In javascript I tried to do:

```js
        public matches(regex: string, value: string): ng.IPromise<boolean> {
            return this.RestService.httpGet(this.path +  this.escapeRegExp(regex) +
                '/matches/' + encodeURIComponent(value));
        }

        escapeRegExp(str: string) {
            return str.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
        }
```

But when I use this regex: `TNGSXGIN02BZ0(1|3)[1][8-9][0-5][0-9]\d{4}` then server-side (java) i get this error:
`java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed counted closure near index 60 (?i)^TNGSXGIN02BZ0/(1/|3/)/[1/]/[8/-9/]/[0/-5/]/[0/-9/]/d/{4/}$`

Java code looks like this:

```java
@Path("regex")
@RunInTransaction
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public final class RegexService {
    private static final Logger LOG = Log.getLogger();

    @GET
    @Path("{regex:.+}/matches/{value:.+}")
    public boolean matches(@PathParam("regex") String regex, @PathParam("value") String value) {
        LOG.debug("GET Test regex: {} with value: {}", regex, value);
        return Pattern.matches("(?i)^" + regex + "$", value);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
When i have this in javascript:

```js
        public matches(regex: string, value: string): ng.IPromise<boolean> {
            return this.RestService.httpGet(this.path +  encodeURIComponent(regex) +
                '/matches/' + encodeURIComponent(value));
        }
```

And this in Java:

```java
    @GET
    @Path("{regex:.+}/matches/{value:.+}")
    public boolean matches(@PathParam("regex") String regex, @PathParam("value") String value) {
        LOG.debug("GET Test regex: {} with value: {}", URLDecoder.decode(regex, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), value);
        return Pattern.matches("(?i)^" + URLDecoder.decode(regex, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "$", value);
    }
```

I still get an exception:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed counted closure near index 60
> (?i)^TNGSXGIN02BZ0/(1/|3/)/[1/]/[8/-9/]/[0/-5/]/[0/-9/]/d/{4/}$

Answer (score 2):

You need to URL encode & decode your regex.

For Javascript encoding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

For decoding in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Comment: English link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Oups. Thanks for pointint that out, updated the answer.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann It didn't work. Did i do something wrong? I updated the question

Answer (score -1):

You can also make use of the String constructor:

```js
let regex = new RegExp(".*", "g");
let urlRegex = encodeURIComponent(String(regex));
console.log(urlRegex);

let regexresult = new RegExp(decodeURIComponent(urlRegex));
console.log(decodeURIComponent(urlRegex));
```